# An empty unity project creates a 22 mb apk. Is this the minimum size for an apk created by unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a new project then built an apk. I haven't done anything in the project other than the steps to build an apk.

below is the build report. THe complete size is 4.5 mb.

[image]

Comment: I found this link: https://forum.unity.com/threads/apk-size-of-empty-scene-is-20mb-after-installation-on-phone-its-62mb.453297/ not a definitive solution, but maybe it could give you an hint.

Comment: Using Unity 2018.2.7 with IL2CPP and the target architectures armv7 and arm64 I was able to create a 11.9MB apk file. With only 1 target architecture it was 6.5MB.